# iptables installed in centos 7 but nat table was not there

Tags: iptables

[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# iptables --version

iptables v1.4.21

[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# iptables -L -t nat

iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.

Comment: I'm not sure if thats a duplicate here, I think it's just that centos 7 is running firewalld, see below

Comment: Are you using some virtualization layer - xen/kvm/openvz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

centos 7 uses firewalld by default.

See here for how to switch to iptables:

http://www.rayheffer.com/essential-linux-skills-with-centos-7-secure-firewall-with-iptables/

I guess the relevant lines to get the modules loaded which you are obviously missing is

```
# systemctl enable iptables
# systemctl enable ip6tables
# systemctl start iptables
# systemctl start ip6tables
```

Comment: Yes you are correct now i can able to see the nat option in iptables.

Thank you Very much.